# What could cause low gas flame on an attached gas grill?

Tags: natural-gas

I have a gas grill that uses natural gas from the house and when the burners are on full the flames do not get very high / hot. I just replaced the burners and heat shields on the grill but that didn't quite solve the problem. I have seen a lot of videos about propane tanks and the regulator on the propane tank causes a problem but since it is attached to house there is no regulator so that shouldn't be the problem. Any insight or ideas on why this may be happening would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Low pressure. Valve not fully open, kinked or blocked gas line, blockage in the grill itself, . Possibly bad air mix, though that tends to produce yellow/smoky flame rather than low flame.

Comment: "replaced the burners" - you did get the correct replacements? My son has a stove which has two sets of burners, one for mains gas and the other for tanks...

Comment: Is the grill meant to consume propane? If so, the methane from natural gas burns differently, and you need to convert the grill's regulator/orifice to play nice with NG.

Comment: Has the grill always had perceived low heat/flame, or has something changed?

Comment: The grill came with an adapter for both propane and methane so I would assume it can handle either. It seemed to run a lot hotter a few years ago when I bought it.